# Cannot reach endpoints in Spring App. XML config

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to understand how Spring exactly works so I've made a simple one-controller app. Probably I forgot something in xml configuration.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean class="com.example.dogsrestapplication.controller.DogsController"/>

</beans>
```

DogsController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dogs")
public class DogsController {
    @GetMapping
    public Collection<Dog> getAll() {
        return DOGS.values();
    }
}
```

I got 404 in `http://localhost:8080/dogs`.

`Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

What's wrong in my config?

Comment: Is there a good reason you use Spring Framework (xml based) instead Spring Boot? Spring boot is much more developer friendly. Nevertheless try `@GetMapping("/")` instead and try if makes a different to use `http://localhost:8080/dogs` or `http://localhost:8080/dogs/`

Comment: @jhueg the meaning is in researching. Your advice didn't help :(

Comment: Just wanted to be sure that you are aware of Spring Boot, but i think the "xml hell" is your research, right?   I wish i could help, but I'm glad I never had to work with the "old" Spring, sorry...

Comment: But I think baeldung.com has some good tutorials on the xml-based Spring too. Take look here maybe it helps: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers

Comment: @jhueg omg you are right. I really didn't try to find an answer in baeldung. Thank you for your research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA: `run/debug configuration -> Deployement -> Application Context`.
Intellij Idea inserted there a full artifact name. I found my endpoints after I had inserted there just `/`.